# instancing vs bufferGeometry vs interleavedBuffer

Tags: javascript, three.js, buffer-geometry, geometry-instancing, interleave

I need to draw thousands of points & lines witch have position, size and color attributes and they're position is dynamic (interactive in dragging).

I was using buffer Geometry until now but now I had found two more things

1. instancing
2. interleaved buffer

I want to know what are these and how they work? What are advantages and disadvantages of them? Are they better for my case or simple buffer Geometry is best for me?

Can you give me a full comparison between these three?

Comment: The two aren't necessarily competing.  You'll likely still use buffers (interleved or not) but draw them instancially if you need to draw a multitude of the same object numerous time but with different position (or other attributes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Interleaving** means that instead of creating multiple VBO to contain your data, you create one, and mix your data. Instead of having one buffer with `v1,v1,v1,v2,v2,v2...` and another with `c1,c1,c1,c2,c2,c2....`, you have one with `v1,v1,v1,c1,c1,c1,v2,v2,v2,c2,c2,c2...` with different pointers.

I'm not sure what the upside of this and am hoping that someone with more experience can answer this better. I'm not sure what happens if you want to mix types, say less precision for texture coordinates. Not sure if this would even be good practice.

On the downside, if you have to loop over this and update positions for example, but not the colors, that loop may be slightly more complicated then if it was just lined up.

---

**Instancing** is when you use one attribute across many geometry instances.

One type would be, say a cube, `v1,v1,v1,v2,v2,v2....v24,24,24`, 24 vertices describing a cube with sharp edges in one attribute. You can have another one with 24 normals, and another one with indecis. If you wanted to position this somewhere, you would use a uniform, and do some operation with it on the position attribute.

If you want to make 16683 cubes each with an individual position, you can issue a draw call with the same cube bound (attributes), but with the position uniform changed each time.

You can make another, instance attribute, `pos1,pos1,pos1.....pos16683,pos16683,pos16683` with 16683 positions for that many instances of the cube. When you issue an instanced drawcall with these attributes bound, you can draw all 16683 instances of the cube within that one call. Instead of using a position uniform, you would have another attribute.

In case of your points this does not make sense since they are mapped 1:1 to the attribute. Meaning, you assign the position of one point, inside of that attribute and there is no more need to transform it with some kind of a uniform.  With instancing, you can turn your point into something more complex, say a cube.

Comment: Nice answer! An upside to interleaving is it means less webgl calls when setting the vertex data, similarly an upside to instancing is it means less webgl calls when drawing.